# why this place can not be found on google places api but can be found here: smallthanks.withgoogle.com

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

this place: (business) "Flawless Website Design"
is not found when using google place api:

```
{
    "response": {
        "html_attributions": [],
        "results": [],
        "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
    }
}
```

but when i use google small businesses and use the same name:"Flawless Website Design" the result is what im looking for:
"Flawless Website Design, eaglewood, ca"[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this place in Google Maps web site:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Flawless+Website+Design/@39.651303,-105.0077484,13z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x876c806eda0db6d3:0xbb32fc6f939d9534!8m2!3d39.6476735!4d-104.9971905

As you can see this business is defined with a polygon, so it is a Service Area Business. There is no single latitude, longitude that defines the place.

[image]

Unfortunately, Places API doesn't support Service Area Businesses. This is a known issue and it was reported in Google issue tracker some time ago. Have a look at corresponding feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187

It looks like Google didn't set high priority on this request and we should hope that one day they will implement it. In the meantime please star the feature request to add your vote.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Thanks @xomena. I just pressed the star to add my vote.

Comment: Do you know maybe how can I get these kind of businesses? Which api should I use..because I see that when I use Google's wizard (as seen in the image above), I do get a result.

Comment: Apparently, Google has internal APIs to work with SABs, but they are not publicly accessible.

Comment: this business:A & J's Removal Services, LLC. has only one pin point location and still the results are: zero. any idea if this is other bug?

Comment: Did you URL encoded the & symbol? I can see this business in Places API: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=A%20%26%20J's%20Removal%20Services%2C%20LLC&key=MY_API_KEY`

Comment: I justed Get (http method) and not Post. now it is working. thanks